# Create Dropdown menu Using wp_nav_menu() function

Tags: menus

Kindly provide me wp_nav_menu structure to create the following dropdown menu.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="nav-menu">
<a class="toggleMenu" href="#">Menu</a>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="test"><a href="#">Home </a></li>
    <li class="test"><a href="#">About  </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service</a>
        <ul class="music-dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Category1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Why us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Career</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

******May be, this type of question already answered, but I cannot understand. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

wp_nav_menu() function does not need the listed items ..

Just add the wp_nav_menu() function in the 'nav' tag and then add the menu items from the Appearance >> Menu section available in the dashboard

Comment: Hi @graphypro, I actually converting an html to wp. The code which I included, was appeared in the menu section of html. So, how will I implement it in Wp ? plz help. thanx.

Comment: Just add the wp_nav_menu() in the nav tag and then in the functions.php register the menu with the hook ... See more at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus

Comment: Hi @graphypro,   thanx for ur answer. but there are various classes, for eg. "nav", "test",  "music-dropdown-menu"  -  how will I place them in wp_nav_menu ??

Comment: you can see parameters of the function in the codex here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/